# setting href attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, href

here is my code:
(note: I'm using Purl (https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl))

```
$("#major").click(function() {
        $(".questions, .sections, #major_list").hide();
        $(".subnav_item:not(#major)").css("font-style", "normal");
        $("#major").css("font-style", "italic");
        $(".subnav_item:not(#major)").css("color", "black");
        $("#major").css("color", "#6666FF");
        $("#major_list").show();
        var a = 0;
        original_link = [];
        $(".major_question").each(function() {
            original_link[a] = $(this).attr("href");
            a++;
        });
    });
        $("#major_list li").click(function() {
            $("#major_sub").text($(this).text());
            $("#major_nav .questions").hide();
            $("#major_nav .questions").show("fast");
            major = $(this).text();
            major = major.toLowerCase();
            major = major.replace(" ", "-");
            var i = 0;
            $(".major_question").each(function() {
                link = original_link[i];
                i++;
                link = url.attr('host') + "/" + url.segment(1) + "/academics/" + major + "/" + link;
                alert(link);
                $(this).attr("href", link);
            });
        });
```

Say I am on the page `http://localhost:3000/university-of-pittsburgh/academics/classes/do-kids-participate-in-class`.  When I alert(link)... the correct link is alerted!!! But when I click the link, it gives me the correct link preceded by... `http://localhost:3000/university-of-pittsburgh/academics/classes`.

1. Why on earth is this?
2. How do I correct this?

Comment: By "the correct link is alerted", do you mean something like `foo/bar`, `/foo/bar`, or `http://.../foo/bar`?

Comment: i mean: `localhost/university-of-pittsburgh/academics/computer-science/what-do-you-think-of-the-major-requirements`.  i understand my issue now though.  i just need the forward slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a froward slash "//" in front of you links otherwise they become relative to the current page. For example:

```
link = url.attr('host') + "/" + url.segment(1) + "/academics/" + major + "/" + link;
```

would become

```
link = '//' + url.attr('host') + "/" + url.segment(1) + "/academics/" + major + "/" + link;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need `link` to be a complete URL, starting with `http://...` (or at the very least `//...`).

What you're giving it looks like a relative link.

Comment: Isn't it better to use only '//' to handle both case http & https? Just wondering.